# PhpUnit ...Killed Why is it being killed?

Tags: php, phpunit

My `phpunit.xml`

```
<phpunit
  bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
  backupGlobals="false"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  >
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite>
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

  <logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="coverage" lowUpperBound="75" highUpperBound="100" />
  </logging>
</phpunit>
```

My `bootstrap.php`:

```
<?php

/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
// Require the vendors autoload file.
/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
// We neeed WordPress Bootstrap files for its test.
/** ---------------------------------------------------- **/
define('WP_TEST_DIR', parse_ini_file('test-config.ini')['test-location']);

// Include the bootstrap file.
require_once WP_TEST_DIR . 'includes/bootstrap.php';

// Include the Functions file
require_once WP_TEST_DIR . 'includes/functions.php';
```

When I run this with the logging section uncommented, I get:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/Freya/Routes$ phpunit
Installing...
Running as single site... To run multisite, use -c tests/phpunit/multisite.xml
Not running ajax tests. To execute these, use --group ajax.
Not running ms-files tests. To execute these, use --group ms-files.
Not running external-http tests. To execute these, use --group external-http.
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /vagrant/Freya/Routes/phpunit.xml

...............Killed
```

When I comment out logging I get:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/Freya/Routes$ phpunit
Installing...
Running as single site... To run multisite, use -c tests/phpunit/multisite.xml
Not running ajax tests. To execute these, use --group ajax.
Not running ms-files tests. To execute these, use --group ms-files.
Not running external-http tests. To execute these, use --group external-http.
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /vagrant/Freya/Routes/phpunit.xml

..................................

Time: 9.64 seconds, Memory: 45.50Mb

OK (34 tests, 38 assertions)
```

Why does it die with no visible errors? is it a memory issue? If so why not say that? These set of tests do include the WordPress test suite class `WP_UnitTestCase` to allow me to set up a fake Wordpress install for some of the tests But as you can see the second time I ran the tests with the logging commented out I get 45.50mb memory used. Thats nothing.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
```

Php version is **5.5.9**

What is going on? (Yes the coverage folder exists)

## Update 1

Turns out that the `dmesg` is showing:

```
[942618.313174] Out of memory: Kill process 12987 (php) score 384 or sacrifice child
[942618.315188] Killed process 12987 (php) total-vm:453360kB, anon-rss:192380kB, file-rss:12kB
[942757.404416] php5-fpm invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[942757.404421] php5-fpm cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[942757.404424] CPU: 0 PID: 16427 Comm: php5-fpm Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu
[942757.404426] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[942757.404428]  0000000000000000 ffff88000200d980 ffffffff8171ed09 ffff88001dfbb000
[942757.404431]  ffff88000200da08 ffffffff817195c4 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[942757.404432]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

Would I need to increase the memory of PHP in this case?

Comment: Check `dmesg` to see if it is killed by the OOM killer indeed.

Comment: The memory used by the killed process is 192MB according to dmesg log. I guess that the VM does not have enough free memory (you can monitor it with `top` while the tests are running). So, you have to increase the memory of the VM (increasing PHP memory will not help you).

Comment: I increased the PHP mem to 550 MB and it solved the issue, the VM has 2 gigs, where as the php mem was at 120M

Comment: The "php5-fpm invoked oom-killer" message suggests that you are using the PHP-FPM (FastCGI) SAPI instead of the CLI SAPI. PHPUnit is only (really) supported on the CLI SAPI.

Comment: So what is the way around this?

Comment: Pretty sure I had something similar to this a few months back when using a specific version of php-code-coverage, but thought it just gave an error rather than OOM. Have you tried updating PHPUnit and dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the best (only?) way to diagnose fatal errors in PHPUnit is to add an shutdown error trap to the bootstrap. PHPUnit traps errors itself to help with reporting, but for some reason this prevents some core/fatal type errors from being reported at all.

I add this into all my projects:

phpunit.xml:

```
< phpunit
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
...
```

bootstrap.php:

```
// PHPUnit dies silently with FATAL ERRORS which makes it hard to debug the tests.
register_shutdown_function('PHPUnit_shutdownFunction');
function PHPUnit_shutdownFunction() {
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
    $error = error_get_last();
    if (!is_null($error)){
        if($error['type'] & (E_ERROR + E_PARSE + E_CORE_ERROR + E_COMPILE_ERROR + E_USER_ERROR + E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)){
            echo 'Test Bootstrap: Caught untrapped fatal error: ';
            var_export($error);
        }
    }
}
```

And these mysterious problems with be a thing of the past.